# EF Code First Table Splitting issue when used with many-to-many relationships

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, code-first

I am trying to use "Table Splitting" in EF Code First and it works fine when I use one of the entities relationships of type one-to-many, but as soon as I use it in a many-to-many relationship I start getting this error:

> (27,6) : error 3018: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line
>   27:Foreign key constraint 'Itinerary_Addresses_Target' from table
>   ItineraryAddress (Address_Id) to table User (Id): The columns of table
>   ItineraryAddress are mapped to AssociationSet Itinerary_Addresses's
>   End Itinerary_Addresses_Target but the key columns of table User are
>   not mapped to the keys of the EntitySet Addresses corresponding to
>   this End.

Here is the code (https://github.com/jorgef/tablesplitting):

**Table Splitting**

```
public class User
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Street { get; set; }
  public User User { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().ToTable("Users");
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.Address).WithRequiredPrincipal(a => a.User);
```

**One-To-Many Relationship**

```
public class Itinerary
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

---

***With the previous code, everything works like a charm, the problem is when introducing a many-to-many relationship***

---

**Many-To-Many Relationship**

```
public class Address
{
  ...
  public ICollection<Itinerary> Itineraries { get; set; }
}
```

After adding that relationship, the app raises the mentioned exception on runtime. I managed to save to disk the generated edmx just in case that helps, here is the link: https://github.com/jorgef/tablesplitting/blob/master/TableSplitting/SavedModel.edmx

If somebody wants to play with the two versions of the app, the one working and the one not working, I have two different commits:

- Table splitting working with one to many relationship
- Table splitting not working with many to many relationship

**Any ideas or thougths are appreciated.**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has encountered this issue:

This was a bug in Entity Framework. The bug has since been fixed, and upgrading to EF6 will resolve the issue. See the following discussion for details:
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1385

A related bug with table splitting validation has also been discovered and fixed, planned to be released with EF6.1.0:
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1611